# Number of l- length closed walks in Graph, combinatorical explanation, Spectral Theorem

Tags: linear-algebra, graph-theory

I have a Graph $G=(V,E)$ with an adjacency matrix $A(G)=a_{ij}$ I have a task to prove two theorems and then to apply them.

Theorem 1: 
$
trace(A)=\sum_{i=1}^{n}a_{ii}^{l}
$
counts the Number of closed walks of the length l

Theorem 2: 
$
trace(A)=\sum_{i=1}^{n}\lambda_{ii}^{l}
$
counts the Number of closed walks of the length l , with $\lambda_{i}$ is the eigenvalue.

I have prooven them both, and found references but! It doesn't work on the example. I have a graph with the following adjacency  Matrix
$$ A=
\begin{pmatrix}1 & 2 & 1\\\ 2 & 0 & 2 \\\ 1&2&1 \end{pmatrix}$$
$$
The eigenvalues are ${4,-2,0}$ You could have a look [here](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=Eigenvalues+%7B%7B1,+2,+1%7D,+%7B2,+0,+2%7D,+%7B1,+2,+1%7D%7D)
The graph look like this[image: img]

One can see that it has 2 closed ways of length 1.

Now it get weird, i am counting the trace(A)=1+1 =2
But when prooving the Theorem 2 I have used spectral Theorem, and when I use it I get:
$$
A=U*D*V
$$
$$
U=\begin{pmatrix}{}
\frac{1}{\sqrt{3}}&-\frac{1}{\sqrt{6}}&-\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}\\
\frac{1}{\sqrt{3}}&\sqrt{\frac{2}{3}}&0\\
\frac{1}{\sqrt{3}}&-\frac{1}{\sqrt{6}}&\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}\\
\end{pmatrix}
$$

$$
D=\begin{pmatrix}4 & 0 & 0\\\ 0 & 2 & 0 \\\ 0&0&0 \end{pmatrix}
$$

$$
V=\begin{pmatrix}{}
\frac{1}{\sqrt{3}}&\frac{1}{\sqrt{3}}&\frac{1}{\sqrt{3}}\\
\frac{1}{\sqrt{6}}&-\sqrt{\frac{2}{3}}&\frac{1}{\sqrt{6}}\\
-\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}&0&\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}\\
\end{pmatrix}
$$

[here are the computations](https://www.wolframcloud.com/objects/931f14ba-e878-487f-b97c-bfb0f2af9d8e)
So basically i am loosing a -1 on the 2 eigenvalue. When i use the $\sum_{i=1}^n \lambda_i^1=4-2=2$ What i am counting here? But when i use $trace(D)=6$ what is obviously not correct. I have used Mathematica 11 to evaluate the Spectral Decomposition. 
Any Thoughts on this?

Comment: Do the theorems assume the graph is simple? (no loops or multiple edges)  By the way, the trace of a matrix is always the sum of the eigenvalues.

Comment: It might have been siad that all graphs are simple. But not sure. I think i have seen this without restrictions, but i might be wrong

Comment: In your notation shouldn't there be exponents on the $A$. In general in an graph the number of paths of length $k$ from $i$ to $j$ is $(A^k)_{ij}$. Note if the graph is undirected it still works but you have to either act with row vectors of the left or reverse the indices. So I'd think it'd say something like $tr(A^k)$

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem isn't in the graph theory. The trace is cyclically invariant, so

$$\operatorname{Tr}A=\operatorname{Tr}(P^{-1}DP)=\operatorname{Tr}(PP^{-1}D)=\operatorname{Tr}D\;,$$

so there's a mistake in your matrix calculations quite independent of graph theory. As far as I can tell from the calculations you linked to, the two matrices you're left- and right-multiplying by aren't actually inverses of each other.

Comment: Did i use the wrong decomposion? http://reference.wolfram.com/language/tutorial/AdvancedMatrixOperations.html I did not do it by hand. Oh i see, i have a typo, but in the link are still correct values. Still lost -1 somewhere

Comment: In the Link the values are correct, its not a static link. I didnt typed by hand.

Comment: @thetha: I don't know what you're referring to. I'd suggest that if you want help in finding the error in your calculations, you should present them in a form where everyone here can follow them. Preferably, that should be in the form of equations visible here on the site. If you want to do it with links to external sites instead, it should be very clear which lines you're referring to. The page you linked to contained various calculations with different matrices.

Comment: One Moment, i will fix this

Comment: i think i see the problem, my Matrices are to exactly Transposed, if i pull -1 from one, and add it to -2 then it will work.